# how to test in case of eventual consistency?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

i have an app ( google app engine + high replication datastore ) which was not using eventual consistency ( high replication ) up till now and all my test worked perfectly.

now, for local testing in high replication, as soon as i moved to eventual consistency, they begin to fail. how do i prevent that ? or how do i test that part ?
i need it for x-entity transaction.

i am using something similar to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting#Writing_HRD_Datastore_Tests

edit:

I need to test the code correctly. The problem I have is with the testing part. How Anyone test eventual consistency ?

edit 1:
I have temporarily solved the problem with using probability=100% in above linked example. But Ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the failures.

Since you have no code and are very vague, it's hard to answer your question.  But essentially either your app code or your tests are not taking into account the eventual consistency (ie, a query may not return with a value that was just updated in the database).  When you turned on eventual consistency in the datastore, the query results you get will be different.

You either need to update your code to handle the eventual consistency situations with transactions, or update your tests to expect eventual consistency results.

**edit**

This question is still too general.  It depends if you're doing, say functional or system testing.  Are you looking for particular results?  Or just an HTTP status=200?

In general, like all testing, you need to identify what constitutes success and what constitutes a failure case.  In a given situation, is it acceptable for old data to appear?  In that case, the test should succeed with either the old or new values.

I'd recommend starting out considering whether you want to run deterministic or non-deterministic tests.  For deterministic tests, you'd essentially want to run through the same tests with probability=0 and probability=100, and ensure you get the correct values for both.

I haven't figured out how to write non-deterministic tests in a completely useful manner, other than as a stress test.  You can verify that certain required values are met, and other eventually-consistent values fall within a valid range.  This is a lot of work, because most likely you have a range of values that may depend on another range of values, and since your final output may consist of both, you'll have to validate that the combinations are correct - essentially you end up reproducing some of your application logic if you really want to verify everything is correct.

Comment: @iamgopal is asking how to write tests to deal with this, you're saying that s/he should fix them. This isn't an answer!

Comment: @Joe From what I understand of his question, he's asking "I turned on eventual consistency and my tests are failing, how do I make them stop failing?", or in other words, "how do I write apps that work in eventual consistency".  Can't really answer that without an example of what his app is doing.

Comment: @dragonx I may not be clear at first so I have updated the question. I want to fix the TEST and not the code. And your solution, "update your tests to expect eventual consistency" <-- I want to know how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The situation you are facing is one of the drawbacks (or call it a feature) of High Replication Data Store. Usually these situations are tackled via transparent caching using memcache. If you had prior experience working with a db master/slave architecture, slave lags are tackled in a similar manner.